# Como comitar arquivos excluídos do projeto local?

Tags: git

***DESCRIÇÃO:***
Tenho um problema relativamente comum, porém que me atrasa muito no projeto, então vamos lá.
Suponhamos que tenho um projeto com os diretórios exemplos: **css**, **dist**, **src**, **js**, **fonts**, e alguns arquivos na raiz como **index.html**, **readme.md**, **config.rd** e quaisquer outros arquivos, enfim.

Agora suponhamos que no meu diretório **"src / img"** eu tenho várias imagens que já foram adicionadas, comitadas tudo isso localmente mesmo, sem necessidade de jogar pra o repositório.

***PROBLEMA:***
Agora por qualquer motivo sem importância eu alterei todos os arquivos em meu diretório **"src / img"** e quando uso comando *`git status`* ele me volta uma lista dos **arquivos novos** e **arquivos deletados**, dai eu executo o comando `git add .` adicionando todos os arquivos novos ao **stage** certo do que quero fazer eu comito as mudanças `git commit -m "Atualizada as imagens do projeto"`, pronto "perfeito".

Porém se eu executar novamente `git status` o git me retorna a lista com TODOS aquele arquivos que não existem mais, e eu quero que eles sejam deletados do meu projeto commitado la nas dependencias do git, porém suponhamos que sejam mais de 200 e todos eles tenham nomes diferentes e extensões diferentes e estejam no mesmo caminho das minhas novas imagens, eu não posso apenas executar `git rm src/img/*.jpg` ou `git rm src/img/*.png` pois minhas novas imagens irão ser deletadas junto.

***PERGUNTA:***
Como eu posso fazer para que eu consiga deletar todos os arquivos antigos, independente da extensão, que estejam no meu projeto comitado lá nas dependências do git, porém que não existem mais em meu projeto local, com um comando só pra eu não tenha que executar `git rm src/img/exemplo01.png`, `git rm src/img/exemplo02.png` ...?

Comment: Já testou `$ git add --all`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eu uso `$ git add --all`, equivalente a `$ git add -A`.

A diferênça do `$ git add .` é que o `--all` também atualiza os ficheiros removidos. O `add .` não faz nenhuma ação com ficheiros removidos.

Comment: Bem óbvio, mas nem sabia, obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Passei por esse problema agora mesmo, e encontrei no SO em inglês uma solução que funcionou para mim:

```
git ls-files --deleted -z | xargs -0 git rm
```

---

**Fonte:** [Resposta de Mark Longair](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6090778/825789) a [*Delete files from git index when they are already deleted from fs*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6090732/825789)

Comment: Muito últil se quiser commitar só arquivos removidos!